# For loop for multiple sequential operations on multiple variables

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataframe with a lot of x-y-z coordinates, and I am trying to apply a specific smoothing function to each variable. Rather than doing each variable piecemeal, I would like to do them all at once. The issue is that each variable has some number of NA values, and they are at different times for each variable. This means that for each variable, I need to first get rid of the NAs, then apply the smoothing function, and then interpolate such that each variable realigns in the end.

Here is what my data looks like:

| occiput_x | occiput_y | occiput_z | pec_x | pec_y | pec_z | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.778809 | 0.136102 | -0.188762 | 0.75975 | 0.147382 | -0.188129 | 1.259259259 |
| 0.782556 | 0.135808 | -0.188076 | 0.763703 | 0.14659 | -0.188472 | 1.261261261 |
| 0.786587 | NA | -0.188005 | 0.768368 | 0.145712 | -0.188456 | 1.263263263 |
| 0.791101 | 0.136106 | -0.189263 | 0.771928 | 0.144896 | -0.187961 | 1.265265265 |
| 0.796484 | 0.13613 | -0.189281 | 0.777115 | NA | -0.188376 | 1.267267267 |
| 0.800031 | 0.134687 | -0.189531 | 0.78071 | 0.143284 | -0.187889 | 1.269269269 |
| 0.805837 | NA | -0.190041 | 0.785133 | 0.142752 | -0.188677 | 1.271271271 |
| 0.810675 | 0.134886 | -0.189897 | 0.790482 | 0.142486 | -0.188353 | 1.273273273 |
| 0.814385 | 0.134734 | -0.189426 | 0.794302 | 0.141631 | NA | 1.275275275 |
| 0.817805 | 0.13424 | -0.188862 | 0.799118 | NA | -0.188698 | 1.277277277 |
| NA | NA | NA | 0.802885 | 0.140585 | -0.187767 | 1.279279279 |
| NA | NA | NA | 0.807202 | 0.140366 | -0.187613 | 1.281281281 |
| NA | NA | NA | 0.811426 | 0.140746 | -0.190012 | 1.283283283 |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 1.285285285 |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 1.287287287 |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | 1.289289289 |

Here is what my code looks like:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(pspline)
library(zoo)

for(i in 1:6) {       # for-loop over columns
  new_df2[ , i] <- as.numeric(new_df2[ , i]) #Making it so that variables with NAs are not treated as CHRs
  new_df2[ , i] <- complete.cases(new_df2[ , i], new_df2$time) # Only retaining the rows for each variable with numbers
  new_df2[ , i] <- new_df2[ , i] - min(new_df2[ , i]) # Centering the point data to start at 0
  new_df2$time <- new_df2$time - min(new_df2$time) # Centering the time data to start at 0
  new_df2[ , i] <- predict(
    smooth.Pspline(new_df2$time, 
                                  new_df2[ , i], 
                                  norder=3, 
                                  method=3, 
                                  spar = smooth.Pspline(new_df2$time, 
                                                        new_df2[ , i], 
                                                        norder=3, 
                                                        method=3)$spar * 100000),
    seq(0,1.998,
        by=(1/500)),
    nderiv=0) #This first applies a smoothing function to smooth the digitized points, and then interpolates those data to reterun to the original number of rows
}
```

This results in a dataframe where all of the variables are exactly the same. How can I make it so that all of the above code is ran for each variable independently before putting everything back together?

**UPDATE #1** I am now realizing that the command smooth.Pspline will not interpolate NA values (my full data set has NAs in the middle of the data as well), and I suspect this was part of the original issue, so I have now updated the code to this:

```
fn.smth <- function(var, t){
  var2 <- suppressWarnings(na.spline(as.numeric(var), na.rm = FALSE, maxgap = 30));
  t <- t[!is.na(var2)];
  var3 <- as.numeric(var2[!is.na(var2)]);
  var4 <- smooth.Pspline(t, var3, norder=3, method=3);
  newsmooth <- var4$spar * 10000;
  var5 <- smooth.Pspline(t, var4, norder=3, spar = newsmooth);
  var6 <- signif(predict(var5, t, nderiv=0), digits=8);
  output <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(c(rep("NA", ((min(t))/0.002) - 1), 
                         var6, 
                         c(rep("NA", (2 - max(t))/0.002)))));
  
  return(output);
  
}

for(i in 1: (ncol(new_df) - 1) ) { 
  new_df[ , i] <- fn.smth(new_df[,i], new_df$time); 
}
```

The above code works perfectly when I run it on an individual variable, however, I get the following error message when I attempt to run the for loop:

```
Error in smooth.Pspline(t, var4, norder = 3, spar = newsmooth) : 
Argument arrays of wrong length
```

It seems like this error comes from the point and time data being of unequal lengths, but I am not sure how this can be the case given the same code works on individual variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2** Okay, I have figured it out! I have no idea why this is the case, but the reason this was happening is because of the second round of smoothing. As soon as I removed this (i.e., removed the second iteration of the `smooth.Pspline()` command within the function, it ran just fine.

Here is the code that allowed it to run:

```
fn.smth <- function(var, t){
  var2 <- suppressWarnings(na.spline(as.numeric(var), na.rm = FALSE, maxgap = 35));
  var3 <- as.numeric(var2[!is.na(var2)]);
  t2 <- t[!is.na(var2)];
  var4 <- smooth.Pspline(t2, var3, norder = 3, spar = 3.619e-9);
  var5 <- signif(predict(var4, t2, nderiv=0), digits=8);
  t <- seq(0.002, 2,
           by=(1/500));
  output <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(c(rep("NA", ((min(t2))/0.002) - 1), 
                                          var5, 
                                          c(rep("NA", (2 - max(t2))/0.002)))));
    return(output);
}

for(i in 1: (ncol(new_df) - 1) ) { 
  new_df[, i] <- fn.smth(new_df[, i], new_df$time); 
}
```